# splitting dataset into list and lapplying lm model R

Tags: r, split, lapply, lm

I'm trying to use the `caret` package to apply an `lm` model across my dataset.

reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10000, y = sample(1:1000, 10000, replace = TRUE), group = sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 10000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.1, .5, .4)))

df_list <- split(df, df$group)

df_list <- lapply(df_list, function(x) select(x, -group))
```

Creating the data partition is throwing an error. I would like to partition out the data using `caret`'s `createDataPartition`, and then apply the `train` function.

```
train_test <- lapply(df_list, function(x) createDataPartition(x, p = .8, list = FALSE))

model_list <- lapply(train_test, function(z) train(x ~ ., z, method = 'lm', trControl = trainControl(method = 'cv', number = 10, verboseIter = TRUE), preProcess = c('nzv', 'center', 'scale'))
```

I think this is a simple problem with working around list structures, but for some reason I'm having issues with it. Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type `?createDataPartition` into the console, you can see the correct usage of the function.

That is, the generic format for it is the following:

```
createDataPartition(y, times = 1, p = 0.5, list = TRUE, groups = min(5,
  length(y)))
```

where `y` is "a vector of outcomes". The reason why it needs the outcomes specifically is so that the training and test splits are balanced for the outcome variable (which I'm assuming is `y` in your case).

Thus, instead of the following code that you have:

```
train_test <- lapply(df_list, function(x) createDataPartition(x, p = .8, list = FALSE))
```

Replace it with the following:

```
train_test <- lapply(df_list, function(x) { 
  return(createDataPartition(x$y, p = .8, list = FALSE))
  })
```

To be clear, the only modification is the addition of the `$y`.

However, this then leads to another error for your last line (the line where you lapply() the train() function).You see, createDataPartition() returns back the INDEXES to use for your dataframe. In other words, to get the training set for each df in df_list, you must use e.g `(df_list[[1]])[train_test[[1]],]`. Subsequently, to get the corresponding test set, you must use e.g. `(df_list[[1]])[-train_test[[1]],]` (notice the **minus** sign). Thus, you should rewrite the last line into the following:

```
model_list <- purrr::map2(df_list, train_test, 
                          function(df, train_index)  {
                            train(x ~ ., df[train_index,], 
                                  method = 'lm', 
                                  trControl = trainControl(method = 'cv', 
                                                           number = 10, 
                                                           verboseIter = TRUE), 
                                  preProcess = c('nzv', 'center', 'scale')) 
                            })
```

Note that purrr's map2 function is similar to sapply/lapply (where sapply/lapply call a function for each element in a list). The only difference is that map2 iterates on **2** lists (which are df_list and train_test).

I hope this helps!

EDIT: If you ever want to learn more about the caret package, I recommend the following link: http://topepo.github.io/caret/data-splitting.html

Comment: Thanks so much. This is perfect. for some reason I knew that it returns an index vector, and forgot to include the step that I subset the train and test datasets by that index vector. I was expecting to get a list of lists, or a list were the elements were train1, test1, train2, test2.. etc. based on subsetting the df_list on `df[index,]` or `df[-index,]`. But this actually works great as well. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful, but as per your previous explanation about the "y" outcomes, what is it exactly that adding x$y does?

Answer (score 1):

createDataPartition accepts a vector, not a dataframe:

```
train_test <- lapply(df_list, function(x) createDataPartition(x$y, p = .8, list = FALSE))
```

Comment: sorry- you're correct. I actually did do that, but then was running into an issue with subsetting the `split_df` list further by a list of training and test sets based on those indexes. does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I think the partition error is due to `createDataPartition` needing a vector rather than a data frame. I think you can do:

```
train_test <- lapply(df_list, function(x) {
  x[createDataPartition(x$x, p = 0.8, list = FALSE),]
})
```

and then your `model_list <- ...` chunk works for me.

As far as I know, this shouldn't mess up your indexing:

```
set.seed(123)
df_small <- data.frame(x = runif(10), y = letters[1:10])
df_small_part <- df_small[createDataPartition(df_small$x, list = FALSE),]

> join(df_small, df_small_part, type = "left", by = "y")
           x y         x
1  0.2875775 a 0.2875775
2  0.7883051 b        NA
3  0.4089769 c        NA
4  0.8830174 d 0.8830174
5  0.9404673 e 0.9404673
6  0.0455565 f 0.0455565
7  0.5281055 g        NA
8  0.8924190 h        NA
9  0.5514350 i 0.5514350
10 0.4566147 j 0.4566147
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `purrr` list-column `tidyverse`-compliant Jenny Bryan-inspired solution. Please, provide your comments how would you make it cleaner.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:10000, y = sample(1:1000, 10000, replace = TRUE), 
                 group = sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 10000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.1, .5, .4)))

df %>% group_by(group) %>% nest() %>% 
  mutate(dataPart = map(data, ~caret::createDataPartition(.x$x, p = .8, list = FALSE) )) %>% 
  mutate(model_list = map2(data, dataPart, ~caret::train(x ~ ., 
                                      data=.x[.y,], 
                                      method = 'lm', 
                                      trControl = caret::trainControl(method = 'cv', number = 10, verboseIter = TRUE), 
                                      preProcess = c('nzv', 'center', 'scale'))),
         oof_prediction=pmap(list(data, dataPart, model_list), ~caret::predict.train(..3, newdata=..1[-..2, ])),
         oof_error=pmap(list(data, dataPart, oof_prediction), ~caret::postResample(..3, ..1$x[-..2])),
         oof_error=map(oof_error, ~as.data.frame(t(.x)))) %>% 
  unnest(oof_error)
```

> What happens in data.frame, stays in data.frame - Hadley Wickham

```
# A tibble: 3 x 7
   group                 data          dataPart  model_list oof_prediction     RMSE     Rsquared
  <fctr>               <list>            <list>      <list>         <list>    <dbl>        <dbl>
1      C <tibble [3,971 x 2]> <int [3,179 x 1]> <S3: train>    <dbl [792]> 2902.691 2.386907e-05
2      B <tibble [5,041 x 2]> <int [4,033 x 1]> <S3: train>  <dbl [1,008]> 2832.764 3.075320e-04
3      A   <tibble [988 x 2]>   <int [792 x 1]> <S3: train>    <dbl [196]> 2861.664 3.438135e-03
```